# Center of mass of Scipy's ConvexHull with provided density function

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, convex-hull, voronoi

I'm using `scipy.spatial.Voronoi` to calculate the Voronoi diagram and apply Lloyd's Algorithm. However, instead of using centroids, I want to use the center of mass of each `ConvexHull` with a predefined density function as the seeds of the next iteration.

While there were already [questions on SO regarding the centroids of ConvexHulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562534/scipy-centroid-of-convex-hull), I didn't find any article on how to calculate the center of mass of each `ConvexHull` if the density is not constant.

Can anyone provide some ideas or example code? Thanks.